# How to use fact in Ansible set_fact?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to avoid duplicating a value in an included file. I tried adding a top-level `name`, `vars` and `tasks` in the included file:

```
---
- name: Install Terraform
  vars:
    terraform_base_url: "https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/{{ terraform_version }}"
    terraform_package_file: "terraform_{{ terraform_version }}_linux_amd64.zip"
    terraform_package_url: "{{ terraform_base_url }}/{{ terraform_package_file }}"
    terraform_checksum_url: "{{ terraform_base_url }}/terraform_{{ terraform_version }}_SHA256SUMS"
    terraform_package_path: "/tmp/{{ terraform_package_file }}"

  tasks:
  - name: Install unzip package
  …
```

That resulted in a "no action detected in task" error. I also tried removing the `tasks` heading and putting all the tasks on the top level, but got the same result. So I've set up variables like this (`terraform_version` is defined in the playbook):

```
- name: Set Terraform variables
  set_fact:
    terraform_base_url: "https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/{{ terraform_version }}"
    terraform_package_file: "terraform_{{ terraform_version }}_linux_amd64.zip"
    terraform_package_url: "{{ terraform_base_url }}/{{ terraform_package_file }}"
    terraform_checksum_url: "{{ terraform_base_url }}/terraform_{{ terraform_version }}_SHA256SUMS"
    terraform_package_path: "/tmp/{{ terraform_package_file }}"
```

`ansible-lint` does not complain about this, but for some reason the `terraform_base_url` reference in the second variable breaks:

```
The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'terraform_base_url' is undefined

The error appears to have been in '/vagrant/provisioning/ansible/install-terraform.yml': line 2, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
The offending line appears to be:
---
- name: Set Terraform variables
  ^ here
```

If it's possible to set up `vars` for an included file (that is, variables which are available to *all* the tasks in the file without duplicating them) that would be even better.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this must be split into two to work:

```
- name: Set Terraform variables 1
  set_fact:
    terraform_base_url: "https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/{{ terraform_version }}"
    terraform_package_file: "terraform_{{ terraform_version }}_linux_amd64.zip"

- name: Set Terraform variables 2
  set_fact:
    terraform_package_url: "{{ terraform_base_url }}/{{ terraform_package_file }}"
    terraform_checksum_url: "{{ terraform_base_url }}/terraform_{{ terraform_version }}_SHA256SUMS"
    terraform_package_path: "/tmp/{{ terraform_package_file }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need intermediate variables at later moments, you can use `var` statement:

```
- name: Set Terraform variables
  set_fact:
    terraform_package_url: "{{ terraform_base_url }}/{{ terraform_package_file }}"
    terraform_checksum_url: "{{ terraform_base_url }}/terraform_{{ terraform_version }}_SHA256SUMS"
    terraform_package_path: "/tmp/{{ terraform_package_file }}"
  vars:
    terraform_base_url: "https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/{{ terraform_version }}"
    terraform_package_file: "terraform_{{ terraform_version }}_linux_amd64.zip"
```

Moreover, there is a high chance you don't need `set_fact` here. Use `vars` section at any level (play, task), or put them in `role\vars\main.yaml` for role.

Comment: Oops, I've missed the 'included'. This complicates things a bit. Nevertheless I don't understand part with 'can't set vars' in included vars. You can, but they wouldn't survive beyond included part.

Comment: You can add `terraform_base_url: "{{ terraform_base_url }}"` to `set_fact:` with this technique to have the vars defined as facts too.